# How to upgrade php on a linux server?

Tags: php, linux, centos

I am running a Joomla website on my Linux server using php version 5.1.6. How do I upgrade the PHP version to 5.3, while making sure my Joomla website remains intact.

The server is running Centos

Comment: it depends on joomla version :) If you need also upgrade joomla, i prefer upgrade using git

Comment: Give Precise Information here, so that stack community can help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have that version availabe via official repositories (check with yum) you can add atomic repos. They seem to me reliable enough so far (I use them for a couple of years now on production servers).

Answer (score 0):

For the Joomla testing:

Make a local PHP installation (I.E. on a Virtual Machine) with version 5.3. Try and get your Joomla installation working on it, if it works? Upgrade the PHP version on your server.

If you own the server yourself and have shell access to it, you can use `yum` to upgrade your PHP install. Here's a guide to upgrade PHP 5.1 to 5.2, It should help you with the basic knowledge to upgrade to PHP 5.3:

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/PHP_5.1_To_5.2

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Centos, but since it's just a rebuild of RHEL you could use the YUM package manager to do it. Of course you have to have some form of SSH access to the server, otherwise you'll have to call your provider to do it for you.

Read read and follow this how-to guide: http://chrisjean.com/2011/06/24/upgrade-php-5-1-or-5-2-to-5-3-on-centos/

P.S.: DO NOT forget to read the deprecated features list in PHP 5.3.x here http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php