# I Want to upgrade PHP 5.6.4 to PHP 7.4 on centOS 6.10 and CentOS 7

Tags: php, linux, system-administration

I Want to upgrade PHP 5.6.4 to PHP 7.4 on centOS 6.10 and CentOS 7. Any idea, how should i perform this operation. What repository i should use for this.

Comment: Look at these pages [php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.php) and [CentOS / Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://auth0.com/blog/migrating-a-php5-app-to-php7-part-one/#CentOS---Red-Hat-Enterprise-Linux)

Comment: and i prefer to use [valet](https://cpriego.github.io/valet-linux/) for easy `nginx` and `php`, very easy to switch between php versions in couple of seconds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upgrade php on a linux server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249580/how-to-upgrade-php-on-a-linux-server)

Comment: Ok Make sense, What if the server is managed by puppet.

Answer (score 0):

you can use folowing steps :
step 1 :we will first have to remove any old php packages we have installed

```
$ sudo yum remove php*
```

step 2 : install new php version

```
$ sudo yum install https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
```

step 2 :Now install the php 7 packages with the following command,

```
$ sudo yum install php70u php70u-mysql php70u-devel php70u-pdo php70u-mysqlnd php70u-opcache php70u-xml php70u-gd
```